# Getting into graduate school and then switching fields

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am in my final year of an honours undergraduate degree in mathematics and computer science.

Over my undergraduate years, I have built up academic and research credentials in the field of mathematical biology. I have done two summer research projects in the field, given presentations of my research at seminars and conferences, received a travel grant to attend a mathematical biology school, have a professor in the field who is likely to write a strong recommendation letter, after he said he was impressed with my work, another professor who says she wants me to work for her, and hearsay that I did good research among professors outside of the field.

When I was doing research, I really enjoyed my work because it was all computational mathematics. I happened to not deal with any biology at all. As I became more involved in the field, however, the biology which I was not interested in became ever more important.

I realised that if the computational mathematics kept me going and not the interest in studying biological systems, I may not have the motivation to continue if I went into the field further in graduate school. As a result, what I really want to do is study computational mathematics. An area which interests me, for example, is shape optimization. I want to become a researcher in this topic, and eventually become a professor as well.

The problem here is that my chances of getting into graduate school are much better if I apply as a mathematical biology student, rather than a student in a different field, because of the credentials I have built up.

So my question is: Is it possible and acceptable to apply as to graduate school as a student in one field, and if I get in, immediately switch to the field I want to study in?

Right now, I am doing my undergraduate thesis with a professor in the field of computational mathematics (numerical analysis to be specific), so I feel like this is a little step closer to my switch. But I am unsure if I can build enough credential to be a good candidate for this field in graduate school.

Comment: Do you mean you want to apply for biology and immediately switch to an unrelated field? Don't do this.  It is not easy to switch departments - you'd presumably need to apply again to the alternate choice anyway, and moreover, it would be taken very poorly since you would have hidden your true intentions. Just apply for what you actually want to study.

Comment: I won't be applying to the biology department. I will be applying to the mathematics department. Mathematics departments usually have a mathematical biology research group. So if I switch to computational mathematics, which is most of the time in the mathematics department but sometimes in the computer science department, I figure it won't be so huge of a jump. But I wonder if this is still OK.

Comment: Also, if I apply to what I want to study but I don't have credentials in that field, is it true that I won't have as good of a chance of getting into graduate school? Is it maybe better then that I stick to mathematical biology even if it isn't totally something I want to study?

Comment: Getting into a reputable graduate school is important to me since finding a position in the academic world is extremely competitive. Of course, I also want to be in a good research environment and have access to a lot of resources, which reputable graduate schools have.

Comment: It sounds like you have good credentials already.  You need to think about what university would be best for what you actually want to study.  Many good math departments do not have a biology group - e.g., in mine, it was part of Applied Mathematics, a separate department from Mathematics. if you only limit yourself to those math programs that have a biology group, you may miss out on other opportunities. And if you write an application letter indicating your intentions are laser-focused on biology, and then immediately veer away, this may raise some eyebrows.

Comment: My advice would be to be very honest as to your intentions - it's not at all strange to switch subfields between undergrad and grad school.  You could still potentially use recommendation letters from bio if they are very strong and they demonstrate competency that transfers to your current interests.  But please don't take my word for it - I would talk to an advisor in your department about how best to approach this.

Comment: Speak and chat with your thesis supervisor and get more advice from him. I suspect he would know more about the competition and how to navigate the issues better.

Comment: @JairTaylor Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can vote you points?

Comment: @jakebeal Oh, thanks, but I don't need the points and I'm happy to let the comments stand :)  Don't take my advice too seriously, though, since I don't know much about admissions processes. Better to talk to an advisor. Best of luck!

Comment: @JairTaylor Actually, I'm trying to help clean up our answers-in-the-comments issue on this site, per [this recent meta discussion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/how-should-we-handle-answers-in-the-comments).

Comment: @jakebeal Oh, oops, I confused you with the OP! Still, I'd rather just let the comments stand as is.

Comment: @JairTaylor OK, I may attempt to condense them into an answer myself, then.

Comment: @jakebeal You're welcome to.